# Excel How to calculate SUM of specific condition

Tags: excel, checksum, calculated-field, sumifs

I want to calculate SUM in specific condition in online excel sheet

For example:

```
Oct  James   DONE    2
Oct  Michel  DONE    5
Oct  James   DONE    2
Oct  James   Pending 1
```

Now I want calculate hours of only `James` work with `DONE` status (Not Pending and not with any other name)..answer should be = 4

Answer (score 1):

Try this in another cell.

```
=SUMIFS(D1:D4,B1:B4,"=James",C1:C4,"=DONE")
```

Assuming data is formatted like this and this equation is in G2

[image]